# Add A1 to C1 if B1 = Specific Number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I will try to be as clear and concise as possible. I am working on a spreadsheet in which I have item prices listed in a range of A1:A40. B1:B40 lists a numerical digit (either 1, 2, 3, etc.) that corresponds with a purchase category type (groceries, gas, etc.). Now I want one cell, such as C1, to add all instances in the A range that equal a specific number in B.

For example:

```
 A1 = $5.00 | B1 = 1 | C1 = The sum in range A1:A3 if it's corresponding B value is equal to 1 (In this case B1 and B3, so C1=A1+A3)
 A2 = $2.50 | B2 = 2 | C2 = The sum in range A1:A3 if it's corresponding B value is equal to 2 (In this case B2, so C2= B2)
 A3 = $4.00 | B3 = 1 | C3 =
```

Comment: `SUMIF(B:B,1,A:A)` in C1 and `SUMIF(B:B,2,A:A)` in C2.

Comment: `if(b1=1,sum(a1:a3),0)`?

Comment: SUMIF(B:B,1,A:A) in C1 and SUMIF(B:B,2,A:A) in C2 worked!!!! Thank you so much!

Comment: If you want to keep these in the same cell (`C1` let's say), you can of course do something like `="If 1: "&SUMIF(B:B,1,A:A) &", if 2: "&SUMIF(B:B,2,A:A)`  which would return something like "If 1: 103, if 2: 299".

Comment: Where is that gold badge dup close @TimWilliams ? :-D

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use SUMIF Function

> SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])

In Cell C1 enter the formula   `= SUMIF(B:B,1,A:A)`

Comment: That's the one! Thanks!

Comment: Downvotes for a good answer on a bad question... Never understood that.

Comment: @Chrismas007 to me it seems the downvotes are in response to the fact that the answer was already given in the comments prior to the posting of this answer.

Comment: I just dont understand putting an answer in the comments,  that's what the answers section is for,    secondly if someone is really asking this question, they probably know very little about excel,   so teaching them a formula and the parameters is useful in the answer - if you are stalking the excel tag for interesting questions, dont write any comments to uninteresting questions   - if you want some difficult questions , ill gladly post some!

Comment: At least for me, I put answers in the comments when it only requires a one line answer.  Also when the OP has not shown the willingness to look for themselves.  This one in particular, the the answer I gave should have been enough for the OP to get the right answer and if he/she wanted could research what `SUMIF` does.  But I would never post the exact same answer that was posted in the comments even if adding a link.  I would have added the link in the comments.  It makes it seem one is wanting points over helping.  Just my opinion.